# Angular 4 Tour of Heroes: Part 6 (Master Detail sample), not working when using REST api

Tags: angular

I download the Angular Example - Tour of Heroes: Part 6 -
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6
and installed it, and it works fine. It uses in-memory web api.

I want to change it to use a REST(JSON) api instead.

So I made the following change.

1. app.module.ts
   changed

   InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService)

to

```
InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService, {passThruUnknownUrl: true})
```

2. hero.service.ts
   changed

   private heroesUrl = 'api/heroes';

to

```
private heroesUrl = 'https://.../getdata.php
private heroesDetailsUrl = 'https://.../getdatadetails.php
```

Master View is heros.component.html
Details View is hero-details.component.ts

After making the changes, the Master view works fine and I see the master data listing. 
Now when I select a row from the Master view - it goes to the details view but I am not able to see the details data. 
I tried to print the hero object (that contains the details of the object selected in the master but it is always shows as undefined in the Javascript console and I am not able to access any of its properties.

hero-details.components.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log('inside hero-details.component');
  console.log(this);  
    this.route.params
      .switchMap((params: Params) => this.heroService.getHero(+params['id']))
      .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
  }
```

What else I need to change so that the selected objected in the MasterView gets passed to the details view?
The sample works perfectly if I switched in inMemory web api but does not work with REST api. The format of the data returned by REST api is exactly same as inMemoryapi.
Thanks to all who respond.

Comment: Are you sure your php code is returning data? Try using Fiddler to inspect the response.

Comment: I can see you're passing in the Id parameter of the hero selected to the heroService getHero method, but where are you actually passing the parameter to the rest api? Aren't you supposed to attach the Id to the getdatadetails.php endpoint as a url parameter? (ex.?id=hero_id).

Comment: Somehow you need to send the id to your rest endpoint, I have no idea how your rest api routes are setup, but as you can see in the first line of the getHero method, the Id of the hero is appended to the url, since you created a new variable for the hero details url, make sure you change the method to use your new variable as well as attach the Id of the hero in the way your rest endpoint expects, either as part of the route as in the angular example or as a route param.

Comment: please dont use the angularjs tag for angular2/4 related questions

Comment: I am sharing the full source code. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6SnMn7u1tmER2pvcm1DQnBnVzg

Comment: @effy in hero.service.ts, I have a method getHero(id: number)    

1. in app-routing.module.ts

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },
  { path: 'heroes',     component: HeroesComponent }
];


2. In hero.service.ts
  getHero(id: number): Promise<Hero> {
    console.log('inside getHero() - SSKKK');
    const url = `${this.devicedetailsUrl}?id=${id}`;
    console.log(url);

    return this.http.get(url)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json() as Hero)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

Comment: @cybernet123 why devicedetailsUrl? shouldn't it be heroesDetailsUrl? and does your rest api expect an id parameter be provided for the details endpoint?

Comment: @effy - if you look in the full source code [link]( https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B6SnMn7u1tmER2pvcm1DQnBnVzg)  it is devicedetailsUrl. (there was a typo in my post).  I looked at the webserver logs and the correct url is getting called and JSON returned looks fine. The issue is how does the MasterView(Listview) pass the selected row (hero object) to the DetailView ? because in my detail view I am not able to access the hero object. hero.id or {hero.id}}  is not accessible in the detail view. Somehow the selected object is getting lost when the view switches from Master to Detail.

Comment: @cybernet123 The Hero object is never passed from the master to detail, only the selected hero's id as you can see on line 54 in heroes.component.ts, the router navigates to the details route and passes in the selected heroes id.

Comment: @cybernet123 When the details component initiates, it has the hero service fetch the hero from the api using the hero id passed in through the url from the master as you can see line 38 in hero-details.component.ts, the hero won't be available in the details component until the subscribe function is called, meaning the rest api request is done and a hero was returned.

Comment: @cybernet123 I suggest you replace line 40 in hero-details.component.ts to `.subscribe(hero => {this.hero = hero, console.log("here's the hero!:", this.hero);});` and you'll see the hero in the console once the api request is done.

Comment: @effy, thanks a lot, I made the change you suggested and it shows the hero object in the console. Please see the log at the log [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6SnMn7u1tmEbTM4QktmSHRBVGM/view?usp=sharing) - an attribute of the hero object shows in the console as Object-->0-->id=2, Object-->0-->description='mydesc'.   The issue I am still running into is that in the html (hero-details.component.html) the data inside hero object is still not showing.  How do I access it in the html - I tried {{hero.id}} but that is blank. Is there a way to access the attributes of the hero object ?

Comment: @cybernet123 It seems that your endpoint is returning an array, try `this.hero = hero[0]`, this should also solve your HTML not displaying problem.
If this solves your problem, please let me know which of your issues I solved so that I can combine my comments into an answer that you can accept...

Comment: @effy - thanks a million - everything works wonderfully now. I really appreciate your help and your valuable time.

Comment: @cybernet123 You're welcome!, I've added an answer to your question (a basic summary of my comments), I'd appreciate it if you accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hero object is never passed from the master to detail, only the selected hero's id as you can see on line 54 in heroes.component.ts, the router navigates to the details route and passes in the selected heroes id.

When the details component initiates, it has the hero service fetch the hero from the API using the hero id passed in through the URL from the master as you can see line 38 in hero-details.component.ts, the hero won't be available in the details component until the subscribe function is called, meaning the rest API request is done and a hero was returned.

I suggest you replace line 40 in hero-details.component.ts to `.subscribe(hero => {this.hero = hero, console.log("here's the hero!:", this.hero);});` and you'll see the hero in the console once the api request is done.

If your rest API returns an array, you need to select the first element (at index 0).